# Best way to get synced audio from multi-cam Premiere project into Audition and back

Tags: premiere, audition

I have a Premiere Pro project with a multicam sequence, shot with two cameras, A and B, on HDV. The total is about 1:16 long. I have two clips from each camera - A1 and A2, B1 and B2, and after A1 ends, there is a tape switch before A2 starts, and then B1 ends with a tape switch to B2. So I have continuous video and audio, even if I only have from one camera at a time at those two points.

Camera A has audio from an XLR microphone. The mic is mono, but the sound is recorded as stereo, i.e. same audio in each track. Camera B has "room audio" with audience reactions etc.

I want to now take the audio from these 4 (in total) audio channels and export them to Audition. There is some noises I have to remove in the camera B track, and I want to adjust the mix so that the XLR audio is clear and the room audio is present, but not dominating.

I then want to export this back to Premiere as a nice, clean, two channel mix that can replace the original audio in the sequence.

What is the best workflow to do this? I am a CC subscriber, keeping up to date, if that matters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Bridge should allow you to open the Sequence in Audition.  If you go to the project panel and right click the sequence you want to edit, you should be able to choose Edit and then Edit In Audition.  This will automatically bring the sequence over to Audition with the tracks properly laid out.  You should then be able to do any work you want to in Audition.

For output you have two options, you can either rely on Bridge to apply your changes from Audition when rendering the sequence or you can output a mix-down from Audition and then import it to Premiere and use it to replace the existing audio.  Since the project in Audition is synced to the Premiere sequence, the audio length should be correct starting from the beginning of the sequence.

More details are available in Adobe's online documentation [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/premierepro/cs/using/WS367138A8-E5E3-49f3-8719-0EFDC91D329C.html).

Comment: Thank you - that was a lot easier than I feared it would be. As you say, I get the tracks laid out just like I hoped, and I even get a video to go along with it. Awesome. :)

Comment: @RuneJacobsen - yeah, that is why the Adobe suite is so popular among professionals.  They have done a lot to make it so that it works well as a production pipeline, which means that applications have to work cleanly with each other.  The only reason it isn't used by the big houses is that it doesn't support multiple users working on stuff at the same time very well, but as long as it's a small shop, it's pretty awesome.